# Is there a fundamental difference between DSP for Audio Signal Processing and Sensor Signal Processing?

Tags: signal-processing, physics

Audio is made up of multiple frequencies occurring at any given time, and we can perform the FFT to get the Frequency bins, but what does the concept of Frequency mean when it comes to Sensor data?

For example, a Triaxial Accelerometer somehow converts a voltage signal and produces acceleration readings in ms^-2. Is the FFT performed with those X,Y,Z readings or the voltages sampled at Fs.

Am I overcomplicating things or is there a difference in mindset when performing DSP for Audio vs Sensor data?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming and it should be posted at [Signal Processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Fourier transform is tool to convert functions or signals into something that is easier to work with. It is a mathematical tool. The result can have an easy physical interpretation but that is not always the case.

Assume you have an object with constant mass and several periodic sin-like forces F_1*sin(c*t), F_2*sin(d*t), ... that act on the object. The total force is just the sum of those forces:

F(t) = F_1*sin(c*t) + F_2*sin(d*t) + ...

You get the particle's acceleration using Newton's 2nd law:

m * a(t) = F(t)

=> a(t) = F(t) / m = F_1/m * sin(c*t) + F_2/m * sin(d*t) + ...

Let's assume you measured a(t) but don't know the equation above. It you perform a Fourier transformation you can calculate the values of F_1/m, F_2/m, ... . That means your Fourier transform of the the acceleration is the amplitude of the force at the given frequency over the object's mass.

This interpretation works because the Fourier transform is linear and so is the adding of forces (See Newtons 2nd law). If you describe something non-linear chances are that there is no easy interpretation of the result of the transformation.

So when do you perform the FFT? It depends:

- If you do it to improve you signal (remove noise) do it on the measured data.
- If you want to analyse the physical object (resonances) do it on the acceleration.

(If the conversion is linear (ADC output to m/s^2 is a simple multiplication) it does not matter.)

I hope this makes things a bit clearer (at least from the physical point of view).